# Can't ping between guest machines virtualbox MacOS Host

Tags: networking, macos, windows-xp, virtualbox, kali-linux

I have two virtual machines, a Windows XP SP3 and a Kali Linux 2020. I can set up both machines on NAT and connect to the internet fine, but I am unable to ping one using the other, or from my host machine. I tried setting them up on a bridged network (en0: wifi (airport)) but was unable to connect to the internet through the guest machines. I think they both have the same IP address and tried setting a static IP on both but still couldn't get them to communicate. Anyone have this problem/would know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with VirtualBox .

You need to create a `natnetwork` , you can do it by command line .

```
VBoxManage natnetwork add --netname natnet1 --network "192.168.15.0/24" --enable
```

And for each VM , change the *Adapter 1* to be attach to a **NAT Network**

After rebooting , each VM must be able to ping other VM and ping outside .

`ping 8.8.8.8` must work

PS: tested on VirtualBox 6.1.8 on macos Catalina

PS1: the network "192.168.15.0/24" from the example must not conflict with your local network or others network to access internet , you may need to change .

Comment: I was able to get them to ping each other, but is there a way that both vm's can also connect to the internet through this method? They can't at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: must be able to acces internet .

Comment: Did you create the network via the GUI or command line ?

Comment: I put that line "VBoxManage ... -enable" into my MacOS command line. I wasn't able to ping google's ip in either of the vm's.

Comment: "PS1: the network "192.168.15.0/24" must not conflict with your local network or others network to access internet , you may need to change ." you mean change the ip address of the nat network?

Comment: @jslamz you must avoid conflict with your local network

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you saying that 192.168.15.0/24 could theoretically be the same gateway as my LAN? If so, would I change that by just setting the nat network to a different IP? I'm not 100% sure how it works.

Comment: i said the opposite , you must not reuse the same network .....  so your internal virtualbox nat must different that your local network ....

Comment: i suppose you local network is 192.168.0.0/24 , so 192.168.15.0/24 is not conflicting

Comment: I mean, yea those aren't, but I'm still not sure why I'm unable to connect to the internet on either machine.

Comment: how many network interface you have by vm ?

Comment: I think just 2 in Kali, "eth0" and loopback. I have only one internet adapter on my windows xp machine so I'm assuming it has only one interface.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Bridge Network for both Network Adapters and verify the the cable connected box is checked. Use the GUI > Go to the Network Settings > Wired > Go to the Settings icon > Then to the identity tab > go to the drop down box to add the MAC address of your network adatper.

Alternately if you are a Pro: Find the Mac Address for your Network adapter using "ip a" on a VM. Add that hexadecimal number to the Network script by: vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/. Add the HWADDR=xxx. Then systemctl restart NetworkManager. Your VMs should now ping. I noticed that only one needed the MAC address.